# Excel #value! error in the formula- but works if the content of text length is less

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Trying to make excel send an email once i have some info my tracking sheet.

The formula used is:

```
=HYPERLINK("mailto:"&$O$3&"?subject="&$O$4&"&body=""%0AName:"&B3&"%0AEmail:"&C3&"%0APhone:"&D3&"%0ASite:"&E3&"%0AJobId:"&F3&"%0APosition:"&G3&"%0AStart Date:"&H3&"%0ATeam:"&I3&"%0ATL:"&J3&"%0AAE:"&K3&"&cc="&$O$5, "Send")
```

It works when length of the content is small. But when length / full details are typed in, value of L changes to #value!

The function is same - it's just the content value length has changed and throws an error.

[image]

Comment: It could be because you are exceeding the char limit in a cell? it's around 32.000 [Excel specifications and limits](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3)

Comment: May be you need to use a UDF here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but it sounds like you're being limited by the `HYPERLINK` function's 255 character limit.

If you separate it out, so that your argument

`mailto:"&$O$3&"?subject="&$O$4&"&body=""%0AName:"&B3&"%0AEmail:"&C3&"%0APhone:"&D3&"%0ASite:"&E3&"%0AJobId:"&F3&"%0APosition:"&G3&"%0AStart Date:"&H3&"%0ATeam:"&I3&"%0ATL:"&J3&"%0AAE:"&K3&"&cc="&$O$5`

is in another cell, say `P3`, then you can change your hyperlink to `=HYPERLINK(P3, "Send")` and it should be fine. You can just hide the column `P` to make the sheet stay cleaner looking.

Comment: Hi, 
Tried that process but it would not take all the arugments - just email id - but will not follow up with body or cc